# Translating radians to degrees

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I noticed that translating radians to degrees and vice versa is like translating a percentage to a whole number and vice versa. For example, to get 60 percent of 345 you do the following

```
60 * 345/100
```

to convert 60 degrees to radians you do

```
60 * 3.14/180
```

There is a pattern there BUT... we use 100 to compare percentages to a number. So, why do we use 180 degrees instead of 360 degrees to compare degrees to radians?

%100 percent = a whole number
360 degrees represents a whole circle

using 180 degrees is like using 50% instead of 100%

I hope I am making some sense. Can anyone answer? Thanks

Comment: I have to say that I disagree with people who are saying this is not programming related.  In non-programming terms, you say 360 degrees = 2pi radians.  In computer programs, you perform a micro-optimization by dividing both sides by two because you've got a handy constant for pi.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from using 360 in your formula. `60 * 2 * 3.14 / 360`  360 degrees = 2pi radians.

Comment: In fact, some languages define the degree to radian constant

Comment: This was absolutely a programmers question. If I was reading a regular math book, I probably wouldn't of been on here asking the question now. But now I realize that flash uses 180 clockwise, -180 clock wise. obviously real life, we don't measure distance in negative direction. only programming does this. therefore its %100 programming question. thanks for the responses

Comment: The value of pi itself comes from how many *diameters* (not radii) can fit into the circumference, where diameter is two radii in a straight line.

Answer (score 8):

The reason you use 180 degrees instead of 360 is that there are `2*pi` radians in a circle, not `pi`. Thus you divide both 360 and `2*pi` by 2 and get `pi` and `180`.

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica, I use the handy predefined `Degree` constant for conversions, which is defined as `Pi/180` or `2 * Pi/360`.

The reason there are `2 * Pi` radians in a circle is that the size of an angle in radians is the length of the arc of a circle with radius 1 that subtends it. The circumference of a circle with radius 1 is `2 * Pi`. In addition to providing a clear geometrical interpretation, using radians also makes a number of other relations much more convenient; cosine is the derivative of sine, and as a result the Maclaurin series for sines and cosines are much simpler than they would be for angles expressed in degrees.

Answer (score 4):

`360` degrees = `2 * Pi` radians

`1` degree = `Pi / 180` radians

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is, why there 360 degrees in a circle (or 180 in a semicircle), and why not some other more tenable number like 100.

The answer to that is the [origin of degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29#History). If you'd like to use a round figure, check out the [gradian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grad_%28angle%29) unit of angles.

PS: SO is for programming questions only. This is not programming related.

Comment: Actually, the reason this question boggles me is because I was reading on physics of animation for flash animation. I appreciate the responses. But if I was reading anything that wasnt computer related, I probably would of known it is suitable to use 360. But Now I understand now. how flash does its rotation is 180 clockwise, and -180 back around to 0, thus giving the reason to use 180.

Answer (score 1):

I ask this question because my lack of paying attention in school. Programming actually is the reason I ask this question because it is now that I am actually paying attention. Every programming formula uses 180 and PI to translate back and forth instead of 360. Since I haven't came across any examples, I assumed that there was only one way. Of course if I was reading a regular math book, I would of known differently.

But I understand now. Actionscript uses 180 degrees for clock wise rotation. once 180 is reached, it uses -180 back down to 0 for a full rotation. Which makes alot more sense if you want your answer to fall in the 180 degree range. and depending on if its negative or positive determines whether or not it is traveling up on the x axis or down and y axis as well. As much as I appreciate the responses, I believe this is absolutely a suitable programming question. For programmers calculating in degrees is different from your average surveyor.

Given a real life scenario, measuring a distance is always considered a absolute value, where programming this is false. which also rationalizes why we use -180 degrees.